# script mouse screen events

Tags: javascript, screen-readers, event-triggers

I state that I have no programming knowledge and I am not a technician.
Is there any software that allows me to click on a monitor event in a specific area?
Should I automate the click to a position when there is a change in color or lines in one area of ​​the screen?
For example "when a line appears at least 20 pixels long, click to X: 45 Y: 230".

Using windows

Thanks for your patience if you want to answer me.

Comment: Not clear what you're after and such questions do not fit the required Q&A format. When registering, have you read [tour] or [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about mouse click if so their is this

```
<html>
<body>
<p onclick=“functionname();”>Hey click me</p>
<script>
function functionname() {
alert(“you clicked the element”);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or did you mean this?

```
<html>
<body>
<p onmouseover=“functionname();”>Hey click me</p>
<script>
function  functionname() {
alert(“you hovered over this element”);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And if i didnt make sense or get to the point you needed i am sorry... it is just hard to get what you mean with little to no context. So thank you

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer but it was not what I meant, I explained myself badly.
I should identify a screen area in which to detect the changes, set which changes to detect and setup a trigger to click in another specific area.